# How to make a python flask app run 24/7 on pythoneverywhere for free

Tags: python, flask

I have created a Flask App in Python it's basically pulling data from yahoo finance (tickers) and comparing it's standard deviation of 2 and upon true condition sends an email alert. How can I keep this app running?
My code of the flask App is:

```
    import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import time

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


sender = "email@gmail.com"
recipients = ["email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com"]
password = "[Password]"

def send_email(subject, body):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
        smtp_server.login(sender, password)
        smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    print("Message sent!")

tickers = ['IWD', 'IWF', 'IWS', 'IWP', 'IWN', 'IWO', 'IWB', 'IWM', 'IWB', 'IWR']

while True:
    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            print("=====================================", ticker.upper(), "==" ,datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "=====================================")
            stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
            # get historical market data for 1 year
            end_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            start_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            end_date_2 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            start_date_2 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=366)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
            # data for 1 year past from now
            hist1 = stock.history(period="1y", interval="1h", start=start_date, end=end_date)
            hist2 = stock.history(period="1y", interval="1h", start=start_date_2, end=end_date_2)
    
            # calculate price change over 1 year using pandas
            price_change_1 = (hist1['Close'].iloc[-1] - hist1['Close'].iloc[0]) / hist1['Close'].iloc[0] * 100
            price_change_2 = (hist2['Close'].iloc[-1] - hist2['Close'].iloc[0]) / hist2['Close'].iloc[0] * 100
            #print("Price change over 1 year (today): " + str(price_change_1))
            #print("Price change over 1 year (yesterday): " + str(price_change_2))
    
            # stddev for 1 year of all data points
            stddev_1 = hist1['Close'].std()
            stddev_2 = hist2['Close'].std()
            #print("Stddev over 1 year (today): " + str(stddev_1))
            #print("Stddev over 1 year (yesterday): " + str(stddev_2))
    
            mean_1 = hist1['Close'].mean()
            mean_2 = hist2['Close'].mean()
            #print("Mean over 1 year (today): " + str(mean_1))
            #print("Mean over 1 year (yesterday): " + str(mean_2))
    
            # subject = f"Price Alert for {ticker}"
            # body = "You have an alert for " + str(ticker) + ".\n"
            # send_email(subject, body)
            
            # alert logic
            if mean_1 > mean_2 + (2 * stddev_2):
                #print("Alert: " + str(ticker) + " is above 2 stddevs of yesterday's mean.")
                subject = f"Price Alert for {ticker}"
                body = "You have an alert for " + str(ticker) + ".\n"
                send_email(subject, body)
        except:
            print("Error: " + str(ticker) + " not found.")
            continue
    time.sleep(60)
```

I have added a while loop as I want to keep it running

Comment: What is "pythoneveryware"?

Comment: @Matthias It is meant to be "Python Anywhere". It is a cloud hosting provider for running Python scripts

Answer (score 0):

I found out that pythoneverywhere only supports 24 hours after this every time I have to re-run the script again so maybe this is a temporary solution and also can use threads to execute the script continuously.